# How can I use htaccess to redirect an exisiting directory to a subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In my site I have a directory called `as.my`, which actually houses the files for a subdomain on my site called `my.example.com`. If someone visits `www.example.com/as.my` they are shown the subdomain. What I'd like to do, if possible, would be to redirect any URL's beginning with `as.my` to the subdomain, and strip `as.my` from the URL. Is this possible?

I've been able to redirect the folder using

```
Redirect Permanent /as.my http://my.example.com
```

But that doesn't work properly if someone were to visit `http://www.example.com/as.my/test/`. I've also attempted to use

```
RewriteRule ^as.my(/.*)$ http://my.example.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

But that doesn't work properly, either. Is there a method available that I can use to accomplish what I'm attempting? URL's would act as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/as.my/      => http://my.example.com/
http://www.example.com/as.my/test/ => http://my.example.com/test/
```

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: Here's my directory layout, as well as the htaccess files that are within each.

The main directory has all of the files for `example.com`, as well as the directory `as.my`, which houses all of the files for the subdomain `my.example.com`. The `htaccess` file for `example.com` is as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /pg.errors.php?eC=400
ErrorDocument 401 /pg.errors.php?eC=401
ErrorDocument 403 /pg.errors.php?eC=403
ErrorDocument 404 /pg.errors.php?eC=404
ErrorDocument 500 /pg.errors.php?eC=500

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(my|www).
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# URL Rewrites (There are a few like this, but they're all the same)
RewriteRule ^about/$    about.php    [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^contact/$  contact.php  [L,NC,QSA]

</IfModule>

<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny From All
</Files>
```

The `htaccess` file in the `as.my` directory is as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /pg.errors.php?eC=400
ErrorDocument 401 /pg.errors.php?eC=401
ErrorDocument 403 /pg.errors.php?eC=403
ErrorDocument 404 /pg.errors.php?eC=404
ErrorDocument 500 /pg.errors.php?eC=500

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

# URL Rewrites (There are a few like this, but they're all the same)
RewriteRule ^help/$ help.php [L,NC,QSA]

</IfModule>

<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny From All
</Files>

<Files ~ "\.tpl$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny From All
</Files>
```

Comment: `Redirect permanent /as.my http://my.example.com`?

Comment: @MarcB Whoops! That's what I had meant to put before. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[You don't actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) You're on the right track with Redirect Permanent.

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^as.my http://my.example.com/
```

Note the use of `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`. According to [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch),

> This directive is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular expressions, instead of simple prefix matching.

That means the match will glob on to the entire request URI and redirect all of them to the subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm assuming that I must have an issue elsewhere in some of my htaccess. I'll keep trying, though.

Comment: By "it doesn't seem to work" do you mean, "I'm getting the same results as before"? (An issue elsewhere would certainly explain that, so I'll see how that shakes out.)

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule in your `/as.my/.htaccess` just after trailing slash rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /as.my/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my.example.com/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work. No redirect occurs unless I include something after `as.my`, and then it just redirects to the main site with the rest of the URL appended.

Comment: Do you have more rules or just use this rule? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: As I suggested in my answer this rule should be in root .htaccess

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the `htaccess` files, if that helps. I put what you suggested into the root `htaccess` but it wasn't working. I also tried the `as.my` `htaccess` file, and still no luck.